# How to compute the time required to transport one unit of flow on a given path?

Tags: modeling, logistics

My question is related to freight transportation, but I am stuck on the logic. So, I am considering a path between two points $(a, b)$ where I am sending $n$ trucks where the capacity/truck is $k$. The distance is $d$ and the truck speed is $v$. Let's say that I am trying to get the time required to transport one unit of freight, do I use the standard $ t_{a,b}=\frac{d_{a,b}}{v}$ or do I consider road capacity (i.e., $path \ cpty_{a,b} =\frac{60}{headway}$)? If I consider
$ t_{a,b}=\frac{d_{a,b}}{v}$, and assuming that $n$ vehicles are not simultaneously dispatched, then which is it ? The time to transport one unit of freight, $k$ units of freight ? Finally, do I need to use queuing theory to compute the total time to transport $k \times n$ units of freight ?

An example would be a minimum flow time model where the objective function is to minimize the total amount of transit time or $Min \ Z= \sum_{a \in O}\sum_{b \in D}t_{a,b}x_{a,b}$, where $t_{a,b}$ is the average time to transport 1 unit of flow over any $(a,b) \in A$ and $x_{a,b}$, the total flow transiting through any $(a,b) \in A$. If I have to solve it, I would need to be able to accurately define a function to compute $t_{a,b}$.

Comment: Welcome to ORSE. I think more context would be needed to answer the question. If you could dispatch all $n$ trucks more or less simultaneously, I would say $d_{a,b}/v$ would be the time to transport *up to* $k\times n$ units of freight.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. In fact, I am trying to create a model where I am minimizing the average travel time in a flow network. Therefore, I needed to know whether the time per unit of flow is $t=\frac{d}{v}$. The assumption is that $n$ trucks aren't dispatched simultaneously, therefore the mentioned formula would not be applicable.

Comment: We might need to see the full model to give a useful answer. Based on your edit, I would suggest just tracking the transit time $d/v$ for each truck and sum those up *if* the total amount of flow (across all routes/trucks) is fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and see how it works out.

Comment: @Bree, Out of curiosity, Why you don't try to use real-time by asking a driver that drives many times this specific road?

Comment: Hi @A.Omidi, I think I will go with the standard formula. I get your point, but to me, it is more about understanding the logic to properly work a model.

Comment: @Bree, one possible practical way is to look into the $A^*$ algorithm that is one of the standard core of the navigation software and seeing how the time can be calculated. But, what the mentioned by others is the right way to do that.

Comment: @A.Omidi, I am the one formulating the model, so I needed to make sense of the parameters. Thanks for your input !